# Python: Converting a Binary String to a Text File

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, binary-data

I have written a code where I can convert the text from a text file `a.txt` into a binary string `Binary`, now I want do the reverse,

In other words, I want to convert binary string `Binary` into a text file `b.txt` w**hich has same text as the text file** `a.txt`,

how can I do that?

**The code is given below, plz provide solution according to the code:**

```
content = open('a.txt', 'r').read()
test_str = content
# using join() + ord() + format()  ... Converting String to binary 
Binary = ''.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in test_str)   

# printing original string  
print("The original string is : " + str(test_str)) 
# printing result  
print("The string after Binary conversion : \n" + str(Binary))
```

**Edit:**

1. I tried to convert the  binary string `Binary` into a text string but I got unknown character, which is not in the text file `a.txt`.
2. If I provide space in `''.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in test_str)` then I can not get a sentence in the string also, I get error, the string gets spaces, which i don't need, I need a complete string without space in the string `Binary`. I tried below code for reconverting :

   n = int(Binary, 2)

   print(n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8,'big').decode())

**Disclaimer related to Duplication Post:**

This is not a duplicate the post you are referring is different, the post asks about "in other words, if i have binary number, i want to convert it to a text file." which is completely different,

Comment: This is not possible because there is no way to tell where one binary number ends and the next starts in the output.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: @AMC Plz check the edit of the post.

Comment: Instead of `''.join(...)` consider joining with a space: `' '.join(...)` Then you will be able split back to characters because the output will be like: `11111100 110001` instead of a long string of ones and zeros.

Comment: @MichaelButscher so should I need to get a different way to get string `Binary` so it can be later converted easily to a text string?

Comment: @MikeSQ _Plz check the edit of the post._ Yes?

Comment: This question has been posted twice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60687701/python-converting-a-text-file-to-a-binary-file#comment107372928_60687701

Comment: @MikeSQ Mark Meyer commented with a solution.

Comment: @MarkMeyer there is a problem! If I provide space in `''.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in test_str) ` then I can not get a sentence in the string also, I get error, the string gets spaces, which i don't need, I need a complete string without space in the string `Binary`. I tried below code for reconverting :

   `n = int(Binary, 2)`

  `print(n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode())`

Comment: If you encode with a space between characters, you can decode with something like: `"".join(chr(int(s, 2)) for s in  Binary.split())`

Comment: @MarkMeyer does not work.

Comment: @MikeSQ I'm not sure how to help "does not work" It's working fine here. The main issue without having some separator can be seen with the simple string; `1z`. With your method you get `1100011111010` which is the same string you get with input of `c:` — there's no way to know which is the right reverse translation.

Comment: @MarkMeyer there should be a binary value for space, why it is not present in the `Binary`, any idea?

Comment: @MikeSQ easier just to show in code. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some way of identifying character borders. If you limit this to a set bit length — like only 8-bit, you can pad the binary and then you'll know the character size. If you don't want to do this you need some other way.

Here is a method that doesn't care about the input — it handles spaces, emojis, etc. It does this by separating the characters in the binary with a space:

```
test_str = "Dies ist eine binäre Übersetzung. "

Binary = ' '.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in test_str)   

print("original:")
print(test_str)

print("\nThe string after Binary conversion : \n" + Binary)

text = "".join(chr(int(s, 2)) for s in  Binary.split())
print(f'\nString after conversion back to text:\n{text}')
```

This prints:

> original:
>   Dies ist eine binäre Übersetzung.
>
> The string after Binary conversion :
>   1000100 1101001 1100101 1110011
>   100000 1101001 1110011 1110100 100000 1100101 1101001 1101110 1100101
>   100000 1100010 1101001 1101110 11100100 1110010 1100101 100000
>   11011100 1100010 1100101 1110010 1110011 1100101 1110100 1111010
>   1110101 1101110 1100111 101110 100000 11111010000111011
>
> String after conversion back to text:
>    Dies ist eine binäre Übersetzung.

Notice the last character for the emoji and how long the binary is. That could be a bear emoji or a couple ascii characters. Without a separator, there's now way to know.

Comment: Hi Mark!, I am trying to get binary string from this code: ` with open("a.txt", "rb") as file: binary_data = file.read() `  then used `Binary = ' '.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in binary_data ) ` but it is not working, I don't get binary string as above,  can u help me? where I need to change?

Comment: @MikeSQ when you save a string like "1101" to a file it's a *string*, not binary data. So opening with `"rb"` is not really the right way to go.

Comment: Is there a way to see variable `binary_data`  in binary format? Name the function plz if it exists, I will google it.